# openlayers 3 zoom to combined extent

Tags: layer, openlayers-3

I'm using openlayers 3 to create a map with vector features on top. So far, so good.

I have several vector layers, grouped in a variable called projecten.

```
var projecten = new ol.layer.Group({

            title: 'Projecten',
            layers: [

                new ol.layer.Vector({
                title: 'EVZ Den Dungen',
                source: new ol.source.GeoJSON(
                            /** @type {olx.source.GeoJSONOptions} */ ({
                              object: EVZDenDungen,
                              projection: 'EPSG:3857'
                        })),
                style: function(feature, resolution) {
                    return lookup[feature.get('landschapselement')];
                }
                }),

                new ol.layer.Vector({
                title: 'EVZ Croy',
                source: new ol.source.GeoJSON(
                            /** @type {olx.source.GeoJSONOptions} */ ({
                              object: EVZCroy,
                              projection: 'EPSG:3857'
                        })),
                style: function(feature, resolution) {
                    return lookup[feature.get('landschapselement')];
                }
                }),

                new ol.layer.Vector({
                title: 'Natuurcompensatie Gasselsbroek',
                source: new ol.source.GeoJSON(
                            /** @type {olx.source.GeoJSONOptions} */ ({
                              object: NatuurcompensatieGasselsbroek,
                              projection: 'EPSG:3857'
                        })),
                style: function(feature, resolution) {
                    return lookup[feature.get('landschapselement')];
                }
                }),

                new ol.layer.Vector({
                title: 'Ebben',
                source: new ol.source.GeoJSON(
                            /** @type {olx.source.GeoJSONOptions} */ ({
                              object: Ebben,
                              projection: 'EPSG:3857'
                        })),
                style: function(feature, resolution) {
                    return lookup[feature.get('landschapselement')];
                }
                }),

                new ol.layer.Vector({
                title: 'Zionsburg',
                source: new ol.source.GeoJSON(
                            /** @type {olx.source.GeoJSONOptions} */ ({
                              object: Zionsburg,
                              projection: 'EPSG:3857'
                        })),
                style: function(feature, resolution) {
                    return lookup[feature.get('landschapselement')];
                }
                })


            ]
})
```

Now I want to somehow loop through the projecten variables, loop through its layers one by one, get the extent of each feature layer, and stop when the last layer has been reached. Then I want to zoom to this combined extent.

This is my basic setup (I'm not good with javascript and loops):

```
projecten.getLayers()
     for (var i = 0, ii = layers.length; i < ii; ++i) {
         layer = layers[i];
         ol.extent.boundingExtend(extent, layer.getBounds());
     }
    map.getView().fitExtent(extent,map.getSize());
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Comment: I don't know extents well enough to create an answer, but I think in your loop you can use ol.extent.getBottomLeft and ol.extent.getTopRight for the layer extent. Store the minimum values of bottom left and maximum values of top right and use those to create your new extent.

Comment: How? Can you give it a try?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```js
var extent = ol.extent.createEmpty();
projecten.getLayers().forEach(function(layer) {
  ol.extent.extend(extent, layer.getSource().getExtent());
});
map.getView().fitExtent(extent, map.getSize());
```

Use the [`ol.extent.createEmpty()`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.extent.html?stableonly=true#createEmpty) function to initialize your extent.  Then loop through the collection of layers and use [`ol.extent.extend()`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.extent.html?stableonly=true#extend) to generate an extent that includes all features in all of your vector sources.  Finally, fit the map view to this extent.

There are a few things to note here.  The [`group.getLayers()`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.layer.Group.html?stableonly=true#getLayers) method returns an [`ol.Collection`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.Collection.html?stableonly=true) of layers.  This is similar to a regular JavaScript `Array` except that it is observable.  You can use the [`collection.forEach()`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.Collection.html?stableonly=true#forEach) method to iterate through each layer in the collection.

Also note that you should call [`source.getExtent()`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html?stableonly=true#getExtent) to get the extent of all currently loaded features in a source.

Finally, the links above are relevant for the 3.5.0 release and above.  You'll need to adapt your code to work with `ol.source.Vector` objects instead of the experimental (and now removed) `ol.source.GeoJSON` objects.  See the [3.5.0 release notes](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/releases/tag/v3.5.0) for details on upgrading to the new vector API.

Comment: somehow I cannot load object into the new ol.source.vector?

Comment: `new ol.layer.Vector({
                    title: 'Natuurcompensatie Gasselsbroek',
                    source: new ol.source.Vector({
       url: NatuurcompensatieGasselsbroek,
       format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
       }),
     style: function(feature, resolution) {
      return lookup[feature.get('landschapselement')];
     }
     }),`

Comment: I've also tried `object: NatuurcompensatieGasselsbroek`

Comment: Starting from 3.8.0 it should be `map.getView().fit(extent, map.getSize());`

Comment: my_vector_layer.getSource().getExtent() will return infinity if the layer is not visible , means we have set some max resolution for that vector layer when adding on to the map . any solution ?